# Rename row variables names in SAS after Proc FREQ function

Tags: sql, sas, sas-studio

I do this to get a TABLE like below

```
PROC FREQ data=projet.matchs;
    TABLES circuit/ NOCUM;
run;
```

```
Circuit Fréquence   Pourcentage
ATP      127           50.00
WTA      127           50.00
```

I need exactly the same except that I want "Male" instead of ATP and "female instead of "WTA"
So i tues it is a renaming function but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note those are not "row variable names".  They are the actual (or formatted) values of your variable CIRCUIT.

Looks like you want to create a custom format to change how the values in your variable are displayed.

```
proc format ;
  value $gender 'ATP'='Male' 'WTA'='Female';
run;
```

Then tell the proc to use that format for your variable.

```
PROC FREQ data=projet.matchs;
    TABLES circuit/ NOCUM;
    format circuit $gender. ;
run;
```